# Linguistics term for word choice

Tags: word-choice, terminology, linguistics

I was taught a word once by a linguist. I can't remember it, but it would be very useful for a Google search I am trying to do to solve another question on a different StackExchange.

It was a similar word to *vocabulary*, but rather than refer to all the words a person knew, it referred to the set of words a person would choose to use in a particular situation. English speakers from different regions might select different words from the set of *swimmers*, *trunks*, *cossies*, *bathers*,  while understanding they are all referring to the same thing - they are all in their vocabularies, but not in their [blank].

My recollection was the linguistics term was also a common English word, like *class* or *style*, which made it confusing when I first encountered it.

Comment: Do you mean all the terms that belong to the same "category"? For example, if I say "_river_" then: _source, estuary, delta, affluent, bank_, etc?

Comment: If you do mean same "category" then "[semantic field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_field)" might be the term you're looking for. But if I read your question correctly, what you're after is something like "active vocabulary" per other answers.

Comment: @Henrik I was thinking about that as well, when I commented, but I don't think it fits...

Comment: Thanks for your attempts. I have found the answer myself: *register*. StackExchange won't let me accept it for a couple of days/two days/48 hours.  [Choose your own register :)]

Comment: A related term is [*diction*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diction).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the word I was looking for.

> In linguistics, a **[register](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Register_(sociolinguistics))** is a variety of a language used for a particular purpose or in a particular social setting.

In hindsight, the definition I gave was *roughly* right, but the *swimmers* example seems to have been inappropriate and hence distracting. Sorry.

Comment: Unsurprisingly, adding "register" to my Google searches is NOT helping much :-(  Thanks for nothing, linguists. :-)

Comment: Actually, I could have given you *register* straight off. I was misled by your question giving a variety of dialectal terms with the implication a speaker might choose between them. To the extent that a person exercises choice of *register*, it usually means whether they use vernacular, standard, or academic words and syntax, not choice of which vernacular words to use.

Answer (score 4):

Not a standard technical distinction, but if I saw *vocabulary* and *repertoire* in the same sentence, I'd assume *vocabulary* is those words & meanings someone is capable of understanding, where *repertoire* means only those the person *actually uses*.

If OP will accept a two-word term, the most suitable is probably **active vocabulary** (as opposed to *passive*, being words understood but not used).

There is also *productive vocabulary* (normally contrasted with *receptive*), but I don't like that because "productive" in linguistics usually applies to *a word or term* to means it's often used to make new words or terms, or has its meaning easily stretched into to new areas.

This NGram shows *active vocabulary* is consistently used more than *productive vocabulary*.
[image: .]

Comment: Apart from the fact that, at least as far as I know, it's not a Linguistics term, I'm not sure the word fits this situation. What I mean is that although it's true that the word might have gained a polysemic nature, for the same reason it's not specific but general.

Comment: Well, linguists certainly use the term *repertoire* quite often, though I see no evidence of it being differentiated from *vocabulary*. I think OP's distinction is largely spurious, to be honest - if you don't know a word well enough to *use* it, I'm not convinced it means much to say you 'know' it. And do we really need a special term for "swear words a person knows but would never use"? I think for most purposes *vocabulary* does fine, and *repertoire* seems to be pretty much a synonym.

Comment: I agree that if you don't know it well enough to use it, even if you do, it doesn't mean you do know it :D

Comment: @Fumblefingers, I know exactly what Texans mean when they say "y'all", but I never use the expression myself. Some Texan may know exactly what "fortnight" means, but never use it themselves. I don't think that is a spurious distinction between the two concepts. (The question I am investigating is about how [word choice] affects people's perception of intelligence.)

Comment: @Oddthinking: I overstated my case. Yes, it's interesting that people choose what vocabulary and syntax to use, since they normally have many alternatives available. But Americans in general don't say "fortnight" so much as Brits. I don't say "y'all" either. Many people don't say "f*ck". I don't see it's very significant that some people *rarely/never* say some words at all. Not compared to the significance *every time they speak* that they might well have said things differently, but didn't.

Comment: ...people's perception of (other people's) intelligence is definitely affected by the vocabulary those people use. More so than it should be, perhaps. But if you're smart and you want to be recognised as such, you can easily avoid sounding dumb. If you're not smart you might get lucky and be thought so anyway, if you were educated to not use words that sound "dumb". If not, people will correctly judge you as not so bright. Seems easy to me.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, this is a [http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/3411/does-using-big-words-make-people-sound-more-professional](question on Skeptics.SE), where the community standards require references to empirical data. You're probably right, but without evidence, that answer wouldn't wash there.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I certain agree it is more interesting that people have words they *sometimes* choose, based on the situation, compared to words they simply never utter.

Comment: @Oddthinking: Well good luck if the *active/passive vocabulary* distinction helps in your investigations into perceptions of intelligence. I think it's mainly used in the context of how children come to actually *use* words after they learn them, so I suppose some less bright speakers will never reach that stage for some words they more or less 'know'. But I think most judgements of 'intelligence' are based on noting the words people *actually* use, not the ones they don't.

Answer (score 3):

**Productive Vocabulary**

> The body of words that a person feels comfortable using in writing and speech. Similar to expressive vocabulary. A person's productive vocabulary is usually smaller than their receptive or listening vocabulary.

[education.com](http://www.education.com/definition/productive-vocabulary/)

Comment: I have heard distinctions between "active vocabulary" (= the words a person would choose from) and "passive vocabulary" (= the words a person knows, but doesn't use). Looks like another name for the "productive vocabulary" listed here, but I don't know which is more correct.

Comment: I'd come across *productive vocabulary* before, but I don't like it because in linguistics *productive* normally has a different significance. Besides which, OP expected a single word. Anyway [this](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=productive+vocabulary%2Cactive+vocabulary%2Cpassive+vocabulary&year_start=1940&year_end=2000&corpus=6&smoothing=3) NGram suggests *active vocabulary* is the more common term, which sounds good to me.

Answer (score 1):

I know this answer is years later but what about the word "lexicon" as the answer to your question?
[Lexicon](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/lexicon)

Answer (score 0):

I have been grappling with a word for weeks now. It might be what you guys were looking for. Lexis? It's something in contrast to grammar, and maybe means vocabulary. But the idea is also "meaning". And that is semantics. Words have semantic context, i.e meaning. But sometimes you get collocations and idioms and these light verbs, look vs. have a look, walk vs. take a walk, operate, have an operation, do an operation etc. In these last cases, you can't say all the difference in meaning comes from "vocabulary."  ?

Comment: Hello. nicolette. 'Lexicon / lexis' are usually used to refer to the sum total of words acknowledged to be in say the English language, not just those John Smith normally uses. Admittedly, that is a secondary definition, but fairly confusing.